# How can I import an array in local file for use in a Vue 3 TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am getting a TS7016 'Could not find a declaration file for module '../composables/httpResponses'. '/Users/username/project/src/composables/httpResponses.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.' when I try to import an array from a local .js file into my view component. Here's the structure:

```
httpResponses.js

export const httpResponses = [
  {
    "code": 301,
    "message": "Moved Permanently",
  },
  {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Unauthorized",
  }
]
```

```
interface.ts

export interface HttpResponse {
  code: number;
  message: string;
  description: string;
}
```

```
App.vue

<template>
  <h1>testing</h1>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { httpResponses } from './httpResponses';
import { HttpResponse } from './interface'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      matchingResponse: undefined as HttpResponse | undefined
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.matchingResponse = httpResponses.find(response =>
    response.code === 401)
  }
})
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? How is this supposed to be done? I searched the web and the Vue 3 docs and all I'm finding is that this usually happens to people incorporating 3rd party packages, but this isn't a package.

The actual project can be found [here](https://github.com/alexmkio/can-i-vue/blob/feature/error-component/src/components/Error.vue) and I tried to create a minimum reproducible code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetsmoduledeclaration-7kpix) but failed (I don't think they offer a Vue3/TS boilerplate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `httpResponses.js` to `httpResponses.ts` and type the returned array using the interface `HttpResponse`:

```
import {HttpResponse } from './interface'

export const httpResponses:Array<HttpResponse> = [
 .....
]
```

then in `App.vue` :

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { httpResponses } from './httpResponses';
import { HttpResponse } from './interface'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      matchingResponse: {} as HttpResponse | undefined
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.matchingResponse = httpResponses.find(response =>
    response.code === 401)
  }
})
</script>
```